# How to get strings from config.yml Bukkit

Tags: java, config, minecraft, bukkit

I have a config file like this:

```
mute:
 MrBahur:
  time: 30
  reason: dsa
 SlayZBro:
  time: 30
  reason: dsa
```

I want to take the names "MrBahur" and "SlayZBro" and print this every second on brodcast
My code is this but it doesn't work why

```
public void runnable() {
    new BukkitRunnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
                for(String x : getConfig().getStringList("mute"))
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(x);             
        }
    }.runTaskTimerAsynchronously(this, 0, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically people on StackOverflow encourage you explain what you have tried so far to get your code working, so just know that for the future.

Anyway, the issue you are having is you are trying to access the data as if they were a string list (specifically, you call [`getStringList(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getStringList-java.lang.String-)). YAML (the format in which .yml files are written) is essentially a more readable/simple version of JSON. Your .yml file would appear like so:

```
{
    "mute": {
        "MrBahur": {
            "time": 30,
            "reason": "dsa"
        },
        "SlayZBro": {
            "time": 30,
            "reason": "dsa"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when it is in this format, your .yml file does not contain a list of strings anywhere. In order to access the two strings "MrBahur" and "SlayZBro", you need to replace the following code:

```
for (String x : getConfig().getStringList("mute"))
```

with the following instead:

```
for (String x : getConfig().getConfigurationSection("mute").getKeys(false))
```

If you refer to the documentation for the method [`getConfigurationSection(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getConfigurationSection-java.lang.String-) and [`getKeys(boolean)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getKeys-boolean-), you will set exactly what is going on with this.

Just another side note to you, StackOverflow is not the most active when it comes to Bukkit developers. I typically answer any questions people ask, but I don't see very many others who are that active on this tag. The SpigotMC developer forums tend to be a bit more active.